# Alternative to "for" LINQ equivalent of Where?

Tags: python

I have a CSV file contents in a variable `raw_data`. I only need certain rows depending on whether the first element of the row (`row_split[0]`) matches a `price_number`. The below code works fine however coming from a C# background I know there is a LINQ equivalent. Is there anything in Python that use `Where` or `Any` which also includes the `row.split(',')`.

```
for row in raw_data:
    row_split = row.split(',')
    if str(row_split[0]) == price_number:
        filtered_data.append(row)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can do it using list comprehension

```
filtered_data = [row for row in row_data if str(row.split(',')[0]) == price_number]
```